# Combinatorics with simple substitution ciphers question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Help me out with this combinatorics question - I understand that there's 26! possible ciphers - would fixing one result in 25! ciphers? Unsure how to handle "at least"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

1.5. Suppose that you have an alphabet of 26 letters.

(a) How many possible simple substitution ciphers are there?
(b) A letter in the alphabet is said to be fixed if the encryption of the letter is the
letter itself. How many simple substitution ciphers are there that leave:
(i) no letters fixed? ￼(ii) at least one letter fixed? (iii) exactly one letter fixed? (iv) at least two letters fixed?

Comment: Hint: "at least $n$" is "all except those less than $n$".

Comment: PS: $25!$ is the count of ciphers where you have fixed one *specific* letter; and this includes ciphers where other letters may also have been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathsf A$ be the alphabet, of size $a$.  That is: $|\mathsf A|=a$.

Let $C(N = n)$ be the count of ciphers of the alphabet of where the fixed letters ($N$) are equal to $n$, and similar for the various order relationships, $C(N=n), C(N\lt n), C(N\le n), C(N\ge n), C(N\gt n), C(N\ne n)$.

(a) $C(N\geq 0) = a!$

The count of *all* ciphers of alphabet, is the count of permutations of the alphabet.

(b)(i) $C(N=0) = !a$

The count of ciphers with no fixed letters is the count of **derangements** of the alphabet. This is the nearest integer to the count of permutations divided by the Euler number: $!a = \left[\dfrac{a!}{e}\right]$

(b)(ii) Use: $C(N\ge 1) = C(N\ge 0)-C(N=0)$

(b)(iii) Use: $C(N = 1) = C(N\ge 0)-C(N \ge 1)$

(b)(iv) Use: $C(N \ge 2) = C(N\ge 1)-C(N = 1)$

Comment: I realize this is old but for anyone who might be using this answer now (like me!), your response for b(iii) would actually give you C(N=0) not C(N=1). (Note: look at the equation for b(ii)! Your equation for b(iii) is a rearrangement of that). Instead, I believe the answer should be that there are 26 ways to fix one letter of the alphabet (you have 26 options), and then there are !25 ways to arrange the remaining letters so that none of those letters are fixed. So the correct answer should be 26*[25!/e] NB: from answer by [tori](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/268426/tori)